# How to run parallel 2 chrome web-drives that one is 'headless' and the other is standard?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nunit-3.0

I have 2 chrome web-drivers for check admin & user sided parallel.

I want that just one of them will run in 'headless' mode (And the second in standard mode).

When I set 2 chrome web-drivers; first-headless, second-standard, 
The standard  mode  for second web-driver did not effected, **And both effected as 'headless'**.

Just if I set  the **first** as standard and the **second** as 'headless', it is works correctly (first as standard and second as headless)

It looks as if once you define the first web-driver in a headless state, it also affects the second.

*I am asking for a solution to the problem, and do not want an offer to change the operating order of the drivers.*

My code is:

```
        private static ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        public static void InitBrowser(string browserName , string url)
        {
            if(driverAdmin == null)
                switch(browserName)
                {
                    case nameof(Browsers.ChromeAdmin):
                        chromeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
                        chromeOptions.AddArgument("incognito");
                        driverAdmin = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService() , chromeOptions , commandTimeout);
                        Drivers.Add(Browsers.ChromeAdmin.ToString() , driverAdmin);
                        break;
                        ...
                }

        public static void InitBrowserUser(string browserName , string url)
        {
            browser = browserName;

            if(driverUser == null)
                switch(browserName)
                {
                    case nameof(Browsers.ChromeUser):
                        //chromeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
                        chromeOptions.AddArgument("incognito");
                        driverUser = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService() , chromeOptions , commandTimeout);
                        Drivers.Add(Browsers.ChromeUser.ToString() , driverUser);
                        break;
                        ...
                }

        [SetUp]
        public static void SetUp()
        {
            SetupReport();
            InitBrowser(BrowserAdmin , EnvironmentAdmin);
            InitBrowserUser(BrowserUser , EnvironmentUser);
            PrintTestDetails();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using the same chrome options for both browser initialization. 
Set up separate chrome options for each methods and it'll work properly.

Comment: Wow, what a simple solution!
Thank you!